# After destroying all records why are new objects being created with an id higher than the old last record's id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a seeds file in my rails app where I destroy all the old objects to start, and then create an assortment of new objects.  I would expect the new objects to be created with an id of 1 since all the old objects were destroyed, but new objects are being created with ids that are higher than all of the ids of the old objects.  So for an example I had 50 Post objects all with an id of 1-50.  I run Post.destroy_all and created 50 more Post objects.  All the old Post objects are destroyed, but the new Post objects all have an id of 51-100.  Post.find(1) does not exist.

Here is my seeds file:

```
Photo.destroy_all
Post.destroy_all
Like.destroy_all

50.times do 
  Photo.create(name: Faker::Name.name)
end


50.times do 
  Post.create(body: Faker::Lorem.paragraph)
end


def get_parent
  resource = [Post, Photo].sample
  parent = resource.all.sample
  parent
end


150.times do 
  parent = get_parent
  Like.create(likeable_type: parent.class.name, likeable_id: parent.id)
end
```

If I run rake db:seed multiple times the ids of each collection of objects gets 50 higher every run. So when the ids are 101 - 150 and I run rake db:seed and the ids are now 151-200 with no objects existing with an id less than 151.

How do I create objects with ids starting at 1 after all records have been destroyed, and why am I getting this current behavior?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want a fresh start, do a TRUNCATE on the table. Merely deleting records doesn't cause ID reuse in relational databases.

Comment: Another alternative if you treat your dev database as throw away like I do is to drop and recreate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just run `rake db:reset` and it should reset everything and re-seed the DB back at 0.

That will address getting the records back at 0, but as to why it's doing that, it's because that's the way that it's designed when you're deleting the data it is simply removing the data and not deleting it's place in the DB which it should do generally. That behavior generally is a good thing.

Imagine if you had a user w/ an ID of 2 that gets deleted or deletes their account and you have user 1 and 3 as well. You wouldn't necessarily want to re-use that ID: 2 for your next user but would rather give them a new unique id for a number of reasons. Perhaps their user ID is tied to records elsewhere in the DB, for security purposes etc. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

You should write this in seed file after destroy command line:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('photos')
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the sequence in your DB, try to reset the sequence after deleting your records by:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE photos_id_seq RESTART WITH 1;
```